# Как работать с файлами других пользователей в php?

Tags: php, root

Приветствую всех знатоков. Столкнулся с такой проблемкой. Есть свой сервер, на нем очень много пользователей со своими web сайтами. Пишу админку, которая поможет управлять файлами различных пользователей. Как осуществить управление фалами всех пользователей при помощи php? Может как нить можно работать в php от рута?

Answer (score 1):

Есть идея: создать скрипт, который будет выполнять требуемые действия и [вызывать его](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php) из php.

```
<?php$output = shell_exec('script.sh');echo "<pre>$output</pre>";?>
```

А при выполнении скрипта передавать php права рута, поместив его в список sudo

```
apacheusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/php -f /home/user/script.php
```

Идея требует доводки.

Comment: А еще есть варианты?